# PrimeNG: p-inputNumber onInput not fired on manual input

Tags: angular, events, primeng

I am using PrimeNG version 10.0.2

Using component `p-inputNumber`, the `onInput` event isn't fired when the value is modified manually. It works normally when I use the spinner buttons.

HTML:

```
<p-inputNumber
    [(ngModel)]="currentPage"
    [showButtons]="true"
    buttonLayout="horizontal"
    spinnerMode="horizontal"
    [step]="1"
    size="2"
    incrementButtonIcon="pi pi-angle-right"
    decrementButtonIcon="pi pi-angle-left"
    [min]="1"
    [max]="maxPages"
    (onInput)="changePage()"
  >
  </p-inputNumber>
```

Component code:

```
export class MyComponent {
  
  currentPage = 1;
  maxPages = 100;
  ...
  changePage() {
    console.log(this.currentPage);
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you type a number and move the focus to somewhere else via pressing tab or mouse left.

Comment: I tried to check if the event was fired on blur in that case, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

update the `changePage` to take the value from $event then you will get the current value you have entered

```js
<p-inputNumber
    [(ngModel)]="currentPage"
     ...
    (onInput)="changePage($event.value)"
  >
  </p-inputNumber>
```

```js
  changePage(val) {
    console.log(val);
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-inputnumber-demo-bdbafg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

another option is to use ngModelChange event

```js
<p-inputNumber
    [(ngModel)]="currentPage"
     ...
    (ngModelChange)="changePage()"
  >
  </p-inputNumber>
```

> the only different is the **ngModelChange** will fire on blur when you
> change the value manually but it will work normally when you click on
> the buttons

[demo ‍](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-inputnumber-demo-jvqmtk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I ended up preferring reactive forms to ngModel and listening to form valueChanges observable

Comment: yes if you use reactive forms valueChanges  will be perfect 